# Нормальный алгорифм Маркова

Tags: c#, нормальный-алгоритм-маркова

Возникла проблема с реализацией нормального алгоритма Маркова в С#.
Задание: **A={a,b,c}. Из слова P удалить второй символ, если такой есть.**
Сам алгоритм я записала так:

- *a|->a^
- ^a|->
- *b|->b^
- ^b|->
- *c|->c^
- ^c|->
- *|->
- ->*

При попытке использования готовых функций в С# ничего не выходит :(

У кого есть возможность помогите, пожалуйста :)

```
string word = Console.ReadLine();
string temp = word.Insert(0, new string('*', 1));
if (temp.Contains("*a"))
{
    temp.Replace("*a", "a^");
    temp.Replace("a^", "");
}
else if (temp.Contains("*b"))
{
    temp.Replace("*b", "b^");
    temp.Replace("b^", "");
}
else if (temp.Contains("*c"))
{
    temp.Replace("*c", "c^");
    temp.Replace("c^", "");
}
else Console.WriteLine("Слово пустое!");
```

Comment: `Replace` не меняет исходную строку, поэтому результат надо куда-то сохранить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удобнее было бы использовать словать `Dictionary` и цикл его перебора. Я ничего не знаю про этот алгоритм, но попробую догадаться, чего вы бы хотели достичь.

Вот сделал с [примером](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC) из Википедии.

- 1 → 0|
- |0 → 0||
- 0 → ""

Как реализовать с вашим словарем, не знаю, потому что не понятно, что должен делать последний его элемент.

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "1", "0|" },
        { "|0", "0||" },
        { "0", "" }
    };
    Console.Write("Введите слово: ");
    string word = Console.ReadLine();
    if (word.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Слово пустое");
    }
    else
    {
        bool found;

        do
        {
            found = false;
            // перебираем словарь с использованием пары ключ-значение
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dictionary)
            {
                if (word.Contains(pair.Key))
                {
                    found = true;
                    int position = word.IndexOf(pair.Key);
                    word = word.Remove(position, pair.Key.Length);
                    word = word.Insert(position, pair.Value);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        while (found); // повторяем перебор, пока есть совпадения

        Console.WriteLine("Результат: {0}", word);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, aepot! Ваш код помог!

Answer (score 0):

Если |-> это исполнение и стоп, то Сам алгоритм работать не будет. Может быть так?

```
*a->a^; *b->b^; *c->c^; ^a|-> ; ^b|-> ; ^c|-> ; *|-> ; ^|-> ; ->*
```